# Jquery keydown doesn't missing something

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi everyone i am trying to make a pres enter to send comment using jquery keydown function with the following code. But i am getting evertime "Please write your comment" error. What i am missing here anyone can help me in this regard ?

```
$('.sendcomment').bind('keydown', function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode==13) {
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      var OID = $(this).attr("rel");
      var URL = $.base_url + 'sendcomment_ajax.php';
      var comment = $(this).parents('.user-post').find("#commentid" + ID).val();

      var dataString = 'comment=' + comment + '&msg_id=' + OID;

      if ($.trim(comment).length == 0) {
        swal({
          title: "Plese write your comment!",
          text: "",
          timer: 5000
        });
       } else {
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: URL,
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
            $("#commentload" + ID).append(html);
            $("#commentid" + ID).val('').css("height", "35px").focus();
          }
        });
       }
    return false;
        }
  });
```

HTML textarea

```
<div class="comments-area" id="commentload<?php echo $msgid;?>">

comments will be come here

</div>
    <div class="user-post" id="postbody<?php echo $msgid;?>">
        <textarea class="sendcomment" name="comment" id="commentid<?php echo $msgid;?>"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" class="send-comment comment_button commentopen" id="<?php echo $msgid;?>" rel="<?php echo $msgid;?>" value="SEND" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $msgid=47

When you do `var ID = $(this).attr("id");` to get the id of the textarea, it will return "commentid47" so when you want to get the comment with `.find("#commentid" + ID)` you are looking for a id "commentidcommentid47"

So you can just use `.find("#" + ID)` or, better solution, just use only `$(this).val()` to get the comment:

```
var comment = $(this).val();
```

But if you need to get only the msgid, to be able to use it in the ajax call, I would suggest to save it in an attribute:

```
<textarea class="sendcomment" name="comment" id="commentid<?php echo $msgid;?>"  data-msgid="<?php echo $msgid;?>"></textarea>
```

and get it like that

```
var ID = $(this).attr('data-msgid');
```

Look at this (simplified) JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zr2r1vyz/

Comment: @finrod ok then now another problem will come. when i press enter then the comment will not showing in  `id="commentload<?php echo $msgid;?>"`

Comment: @fidrod so when i refresh the page then i see my comment on that time.

Comment: @innovation You can save the msgid in the DOM : `<textarea ... data-mdgid="<?php echo $msgid;?>"></textarea>` and get it when pressing ENTER with `var ID = $(this).attr('data-msgid');`

Comment: @Finrod It is posting the message and msgid But just success: function(html) { ... } didn't working.

Comment: Add an error callback to your $.ajax to see what is the problem:
`error:function(e){console.log(e);}`

Comment: @Finrod please click [ScreenShot](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/11988663_178489522484215_6445886008012894994_n.jpg?oh=9598b53d8b99f5e1aefe4a51cab46a48&oe=56A6C6A2&__gda__=1449233300_9a45c4cecf7f5266c2d82076362ad997)

Comment: @innovation sorry, it's logging the event, not the ajax error, use `error:function(error){console.log(error);}`

Comment: @Finrod then problem is when i write comment and press enter it need to show my comment in `$("#commentload" + ID).append(html);`but it didn't show. If i refresh the page then i see my comment.

Comment: @innovation, perhaps you html value is empty, it seems to be another issue. If so, please ask another question to avoir extended discussion in comments

Answer (score 1):

Given your information, I would think that you have an issue with your selector for the `comment` variable since your test always tells you that your comment value has a length of 0.

Also, since you seem to have the comment ID, why don't you just use this simpler selector: `$('#commentid' + ID)`?